# I couldn't find why there is a minus sign in the result

Tags: python, python-requests

I attached my homework below, actually I implemented the whole code but there is something wrong i guess because there is a minus sign in the result which shouldn't be. Could you please help me to find why this is? I'm adding the link of the .pdb file which is needed for homework here(for explanation please look at the image below): https://drive.google.com/file/d/179dg3EQ6gE--Y7cSVM8zw0_QT3wHARKU/view?usp=sharing

```
#my result is this:
"""Center of mass of the protein is 30.317, 28.775, 15.353
   New center of mass of the protein is  0.000, -0.000,  0.000"""
#and it should be like that:
"""Center of mass of the protein is 30.317, 28.775, 15.353
   New center of mass of the protein is  0.000, 0.000,  0.000"""
```

Here is my whole code and the explanation of my hw:(The code below the last def does not belong to me, that part is there for checking the hw and written by instructer.)

[image]

```
def protein_parser(pdbfile):
    file = open("1ubq.pdb", 'r')
    listem = []
    for line in file:
        a = line.split()
        tip = a[0]
        if tip == "ATOM":
            x= a[6]
            y = a[7]
            z = a[8]
            el = a[11]
            listem.append(float(x))
            listem.append(float(y))
            listem.append(float(z))
            listem.append(el)
        
    listem2 = []
    for i in range(0,len(listem)+1,4):
        if not i == len(listem):
            listem2.append(listem[i:i+4])
    
    atoms = listem2
    return atoms

def center_of_mass(atoms):
    """Calculate the center of mass."""
    mass={'C':12.01, 'O':16.00, 'H':1.008, 'N': 14.01, 'S':32.06}
    ri = []
    rix = []
    riy = []
    riz = []
    at = []
    nnum = 0
    cnum = 0
    onum = 0
    hnum = 0
    snum = 0
    for a in atoms:
        at.append(a[3])
    for e in atoms:
        ri.append(e[0:3])
    for c in ri:
        rix.append(c[0])
        riy.append(c[1])
        riz.append(c[2])
    
    #print(ri[599-1],atoms[599-1][4-1])
    #print(mass.get(atoms[0][3]))
    topx = float()
    topy = float()
    topz = float()
    for i in range(len(atoms)):
        topx += (mass.get(atoms[i][3])) * (rix[i])
        topy += (mass.get(atoms[i][3])) * (riy[i])
        topz += (mass.get(atoms[i][3])) * (riz[i])
    for a in at:
        if a == 'N':
            nnum += 1
        if a == 'C':
            cnum += 1
        if a == 'S':
            snum += 1
        if a == 'H':
            hnum += 1
        if a == 'O':
            onum += 1
    nM = 14.01 * nnum
    cM = 12.01 * cnum
    sM = 32.06 * snum
    hM = 1.008 * hnum
    oM = 16.00 * onum
    M = nM + cM + sM + hM + oM
    cm = [((1/M) * topx) , ((1/M) * topy) , ((1/M) * topz)]
    
    return cm

def shift(atoms,vec):
    """shift the protein defined in atoms by the vector vec"""
    """atoms should not be modified, function should return atomsnew
    list with the updated coordinates"""
    atomsnew = [[0 for eleman in range(4)] for eleman in range(len(atoms))]
    for i in range(len(atoms)):
        atomsnew[i][0] = atoms[i][0] + vec[0] #xvalueupdated
        atomsnew[i][1] = atoms[i][1] + vec[1] #yvalueupdated
        atomsnew[i][2] = atoms[i][2] + vec[2] #zvalueupdated
        atomsnew[i][3] = atoms[i][3]          #atomsnamesinserted
    return atomsnew
    


atoms=protein_parser('1ubq.pdb')

com=center_of_mass(atoms[:])
print(f"Center of mass of the protein is {com[0]:6.3f}, {com[1]:6.3f}, {com[2]:6.3f}")

#If we shift the protein by vector -com, 
#it's center of mass will be at the origin
for i in range(3):
    com[i] *= -1
atomsnew=shift(atoms,com)

com=center_of_mass(atomsnew[:])
print(f"New center of mass of the protein is {com[0]:6.3f}, {com[1]:6.3f}, {com[2]:6.3f}")

"""
Expected output is:
Center of mass of the protein is 30.317, 28.775, 15.353
New center of mass of the protein is  0.000,  0.000,  0.000
```

Comment: There's no error, it's just a thing about how numbers are represented in a computer

Comment: Your actual number may be something like -0.00001234, so it's close to zero, but yet negative, so when you format with 3 fractional digits, you get the minus

Comment: You may try to `{round(com[0], 3):6.3f}` when you print the values, so you don't just cut off the last fractional, but actually round to the 3rd digit

Comment: Actually I agree but my instructor says that it should not be like that :( I asked for help from him but he does not help for any part of homeworks. Also, I am not allowed to implement the code below the last shifting def, so i cannot try that one i guess and I don't know where to write that code.

Comment: you can set `com[0] = 0.0 if abs(round(com[0],3)) < 0.0001 else round(com[0],3)` for all three values of `com`

Comment: so you basically turn very small negative values into positive zeros

Comment: com is defined in below the definitions and I am not allowed to implement that part, so i don't know where to write the code that you wrote. I'm new at learning python, sorry for that :( If you have time, could you explain where I should write that code to? If you don't have time, nevermind, i will handle it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Okay, you can change the values in `center_of_mass` right before you return the `cm`

Comment: It actually can be `if abs(cm[0]) < 0.0001: cm[0] = abs(cm[0])` for all three values

Comment: yeah it's fixed now, thanks my friend :)